# How would you say "Family before wealth" in Japanese?

Tags: translation

My friend wants to get a japanese phrase on some t-shirts for our group of friends, and he wants it to say "family before fortune." He means fortune as in wealth, not as in luck, or future. The problem is he has already "translated" it-- he basically put it in google translate and it spat out "unmei no mae no kazoku" which doesn't seem right to me. "Unmei" doesn't mean that kind of fortune. I told him "tomi" would probably make the most sense, but I'm not sure about the grammar and/or linguistics in the sentence itself. I don't know too much Japanese, so if anyone could answer this, and include the romanization & kanji, that would be great.

Comment: 「お金{おかね}より家族{かぞく}」かな…？

Comment: "Unmei no mae no kazoku" (運命の前の家族) means "A family faced with a doom" :)

Answer (score 2):

家庭優先
（かていゆうせん）
katei yuusen

This is a compound word used usually in relation to the work-life balance, meaning to "prioritize family" (over work, a career, wealth, etc). I think it works well in your case as well.

Comment: That however implies that you have a family and you prioritize it over work, whereas in my understanding, LeoD is asking for something more along the lines of "I prefer having a family over having a lot of money", but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: This is a very versatile phrase and although it has connotations toward the work-life balance it also just has its direct meaning of "prioritizing family" which I think served sufficient for Leo D. I was under the impression "family before fortune" pertained to the work-life balance but even in the instance that it means to get married and have kids instead of becoming someone driven primarily by career, as you say, this phrase absolutely still applies.